PDFBox 3 adds padding before text
I'm experiencing an issue with Apache PDFBox version 3 where it seems to add padding or a blank line before rendering text. This was not the case with PDFBox version 2. I have been using the PDPageContentStream class to render text, and the same code that worked perfectly in version 2 now introduces extra spacing in version 3. Has anyone had this sort of problem and please what is the solution? 
I have tried various PDPageContentStream methods including setLeading with no luck

Please include the code, the exact versions (with 2 and 3) and links to the result PDFs.

Upgrading from 2.0.13 to 3.0.2. The main changes are using Loader to get a PDF document and a new constructor for PDType1Font, using the new Enum Standard14Fonts.FontName. Everything else is the same.

Please include the pivotal code and links to the original and result PDFs.

It would be interesting what happens with 2.0.31 which is the current 2.0 version. If it also has the anomaly, then you could find out when this changed.

Old Code
contentStream.beginText();
contentStream.newLineAtOffset(textXPosition, textYPosition);
contentStream.setFont(PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD, 11);
contentStream.setFont(FONT_HELVETICA_BOLD, 11);
contentStream.showText(replacedCertificateText);
contentStream.endText();
...
DiagonalFont diagonalFont =
DiagonalFont.builder()
.font(PDType1Font.HELVETICA)
.fontSize(110)
.text("SPECIMEN")
.build();

new code
private final PDType1Font FONT_HELVETICA = new PDType1Font(Standard14Fonts.FontName.HELVETICA);
private final PDType1Font FONT_HELVETICA_BOLD = new PDType1Font(Standard14Fonts.FontName.HELVETICA_BOLD);
contentStream.beginText();
contentStream.newLineAtOffset(textXPosition, textYPosition);
contentStream.setFont(FONT_HELVETICA_BOLD, 11);
contentStream.showText(replacedCertificateText);
contentStream.endText();

You need to include code that actually runs. Ideally include textXPosition and textYPosition in the output so that you're sure it's the same values.
